# Javascript function is not closing the opened tab

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which is as follows

```
function allsave(){
  var list = document.getElementById("tableData").getElementsByTagName('a');
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    tab=window.open(list[i], '_blank');
    setTimeout("tab.close()", 1);
    if(tab.closed === true){
      continue;
    }
  }
```

I am expecting that when the function is called it will open a new tab which is inside the array and close the same then open the next. But I am unable to do the same this function simply opens the tabs without closing it where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a closure over the `tab` name, not the string form of `setTimeout`, which basically runs things in the global scope.

```
function allsave() {
  var list = document.getElementById("tableData").getElementsByTagName("a");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const tab = window.open(list[i], "_blank");
    setTimeout(() => tab.close(), 1);
    if (tab.closed === true) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```